# which CPUs support MOVBE instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, endianness

Sometimes GCC generates this instruction when compiling with `-march=atom`. Does each and every Intel Atom CPU support MOVBE?

What other processors support this instruction? I can't seem to find this information on Intel website. Please help.

Comment: [Athlon X4 845](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Bulldozer/AMD-Athlon%20X4%20845.html) a.k.a Bulldozer has it too.

Comment: @jww: Athlon X4 845 is [Excavator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excavator_(microarchitecture)) (final generation Bulldozer-family), not Bulldozer.  Steamroller and earlier don't have MOVBE.  http://instlatx64.atw.hu/ has CPUID listings and instruction microbenchmarks that show only Carrizo (Excavator) CPUs have it, not earlier in that family.

Comment: @Peter - I bought a bulldozer machine that has it. It is sitting in my basement.

Comment: @jww: I highly doubt that, unless it's supported but not reported by CPUID.  `0x1E98220B & (1<<21) = 0`.  (That's `CPUID.01H:ECX.MOVBE[bit 22]` from the CPUID dump on a Bulldozer, specifically http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/AuthenticAMD0600F12_K15_Zambezi6C_CPUID.txt).  I'm more inclined to trust CPUID dumps from instlat than your memory about your basement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This instruction was originally unique to the Intel® Atom™ processor.

From Intel side:

> The Intel® Compilers 11.0 allow you
>   to target the Intel® Atom™ processor
>   using the /QxSSE3_ATOM or -xSSE3_ATOM
>   compiler options.  These options
>   enable the generation of the movbe
>   instruction which is unique to the
>   Intel® Atom™ processor.

In other microarchitectures (http://instlatx64.atw.hu/ with uop info from https://agner.org/optimize/):

- Mainstream Intel: Haswell and later.  Including Haswell Xeon (Ex-xxxx v3).
  Decodes as 2 or 3 uops, about the same as `bswap` + load or store.
- Mainstream AMD: [Excavator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excavator_(microarchitecture)), and Ryzen-family.  Steamroller and earlier don't have it.
  Decodes efficiently to a single uop.

non-mainstream CPUs:

- Legacy in-order Intel Atom: all
- Intel Silvermont-family out-of-order Atom: all.  Decodes efficiently to a single uop.
- AMD Jaguar.  Decodes efficiently to a single uop.
- Intel Xeon Phi: Knight's Landing (based on Silvermont) and later.  (Maybe not on Knight's corner.)

Comment: Now [supported](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/05/a-look-at-haswell/) by Haswell SoC as well.

Comment: Intel Xeon E5-2640 supports it as well.

Comment: @pchaigno: E5-2640 is Sandybridge.  Only E5-2640 v3 and later support MOVBE.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that all Atom processors support MOVBE; at any rate, the first and least capable (the Atom 230) does. (See e.g. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/proc-cpuinfo-output-816192/ for evidence.) I don't believe any non-Atom Intel processors support MOVBE; at any rate, recent Core i7 processors appear not to (see e.g. http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f108/i7-running-on-3-of-8-threads-522063.html and search for "movbe" for evidence).

You can detect MOVBE support at runtime using CPUID.

Comment: Interesting.  [Agner Fog's instruction tables](https://agner.org/optimize/) only list it for Silvermont and later, but that `/proc/cpuid` confirms that in-order Atom 230 had it too. 
 https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/35635/intel-atom-processor-230-512k-cache-1-60-ghz-533-mhz-fsb.html.  Apparently Agner didn't add it to his tests until then.

Answer (score 2):

Based on /proc/cpuinfo, the new Xeon E3 XXXX v3 also support MOVBE

Source:

http://openbenchmarking.org/s/Intel%20Xeon%20E3-1230%20v3

Comment: Xeon v3 is Haswell microarchitecture, so yes.